# cakephp automatic logout from application when creating a user with existing email address

Tags: cakephp

In my application I have a users table with username(email) and password, there is no validation rules on username but when I try to create username already exist in users table then it automatically log me out from application without any error.
Users controller:

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

class UsersController extends AppController {

    public $components = array('Recaptcha.Recaptcha');
    public $helpers = array('Recaptcha.Recaptcha');
    var $uses = array('User', 'Student');

    function isAuthorized() {
        $userType = $this->Auth->user('type'); ///loggen-in $userType=1

        switch ($userType) {
            case 1:
                if (in_array($this->action, array('admin_add'))) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            case 2:
                if (in_array($this->action, array('admin_dashboard'))) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
        }
    }

    public function admin_add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->create();
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'), 'success');
                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'error');
            }
        }
        $this->layout = 'admin_default';
    }
}
```

User model:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class User extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
        'password' => array(
            'min' => array(
                'rule' => array('minLength', 3),
                'message' => 'Password must be at least 3 characters.'
            ),
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'Please enter a password.'
            ),
        ),
        'cpassword' => array(
            'required' => 'notEmpty',
            'match' => array(
                'rule' => 'validatePasswdConfirm',
                'message' => 'Passwords do not match'
            )
        )
    );



function validatePasswdConfirm($data) {
        if ($this->data['User']['password'] !== $this->data['User']['cpassword']) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

User view:

```
    <?php

echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'admin_add',
    'id' => 'form-register',
    'class' => 'form-horizontal form-bordered'
));
echo $this->Form->input('username', array(
    'id' => 'user-name',
    'class' => 'form-control input-lg',
    'placeholder' => 'Email',
    'label' => false
));
echo $this->Form->input('password', array(
    'id' => 'user-password',
    'class' => 'form-control input-lg',
    'placeholder' => 'Password',
    'label' => false
));
echo $this->Form->input('cpassword', array(
    'id' => 'user-cpassword',
    'class' => 'form-control input-lg',
    'placeholder' => 'confirm Password',
    'label' => false,
    'type' => 'password'
));
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

What is the issue and how can I fix this?

Comment: i can't see any error , but i think you should add a check before saving the data ; a check if the username / email exists in the database show an error message and don't save ... cause it will create ambiguity for the auth composer and might not work .

Comment: I added but With this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990466/cakephp-isunique-is-not-working-properly
Then I removed it but still the problem exist...Thanks for you reply

Comment: Actually it logout the current logged-in user.....

Comment: did u add a check of the username before saving the new one ?

Comment: I added it but there was also an issue as :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990466/cakephp-isunique-is-not-working-properly

Answer (score 0):

I suggest an other way , add this function on your model :

```
function UsernameExists($username){
    $count = $this->Event->find("count", array("conditions" => array("username" => $username)));
    if ($count == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and on your controller in your save function :

```
public function save($post){
if($this->User->UsernameExists($username)){
    //show an error message that you cannot add because the username exists 
} else {
    $this->User->save($data);
}

}
```

Comment: may saghira, The actual problem is it  doesn't go to the post function when I try to create a user with existing user. Another thing is admin user is logged in to add a user.

Comment: i don't get you , when exactly it does log out ? what's the action you do just before it logs out ?

Comment: Its very strange issue, I am not sure whats wrong with it. Even If i remove username validation and when I try to create a user with already exist email address it doesn't go to post function and redirected to a page "The page isn't redirected properly "....

Comment: but you can create a user with a username different doesn't exist in db ?

Comment: strange , i've never faced that problem , i would like to try myself in one of my applications with cakephp but i can't now , sorry !

Comment: Yes Its strange but it is. Anyhow thanks for your time.

Comment: i've try it in a application of mine , and it doesn't show any error and no strange behavior , just revise your code and your auth function.

Comment: Thanks, I revise my code but nothing find wrong in it.